# Horizontal flatlist item not adapting to device orientation changes

Tags: react-native, orientation, flatlist

So i'm making an email client. On the message view screen there is a header (from, to, subject) and a WebView for content. Each message is a child in a horizontal Flatlist with paging in order to swipe through each message, just like Gmail for example.

The problem is, when I rotate the device, it never adjusts right. It takes really long time to fire the event that the width has changed, and when it eventually does it goes offset like in between 2 messages but not exactly in the middle.

I used every hook and listener possible (Dimensions, useDeviceOrientation, onLayout etc) I've search everywhere but no one seems to have had this issue before. So in my last hope, do you know anything that can help me with that ?

I have narrowed down the root cause to be (probably) at getItemLayout which needs to be set in order to use flatlist.scrollTo() method. Somehow I've managed to get a proper end result with a combination of all of the above but there is still a big delay and clumsiness so I believe there has to be something that I'm missing

Here you can see exactly what I'm talking about [example video](https://youtube.com/shorts/Y7VtsvwWHA0?feature=share)

Not posting code because it doesn't really matter. U can just write in expo a plain horizontal flatlist with paging and rotate the device that's literally it

Comment: Hi Manolee, Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: yes. well kinda actually. Let's say we have screen A and Screen B. Screen A is the a simple flatlist just like the home screen of gmail app where rows are emails and when you tap to one you go to screen B which is the horizontal pager that im talking about. So i did a profiler analysis and found out that the previous screen (A) was alive when i was on screen B. So when i rotated my device, all of the rows of flatlist on screen A, were re-rendered to adapt to new width... what i did was to freeze screen A when im on screen B. PS: using react-navgation & react-native-screens